# sed command working in command line but not in my script file

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sed

I am trying to replace angular service files with the
script below:

```
find . -type f -name "*.service.ts" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's,http://localhost:8080,'',g'
```

When I run it in Ubuntu it works fine, but when I execute a script file with the same line it give me this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 27: unknown option to `s'
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Look a [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/95939/how-exactly-do-i-create-a-sed-script-and-use-it-to-edit-a-file)

Comment: Your `sed` command is GNU specific, so, are you running the _script_ on Linux?

Comment: An argument of your `sed` command looks strange: `'s,http://localhost:8080,'',g'`. You concatenate two strings delimited by `'`. Why don't you just code `'s,http://localhost:8080,,g'`?

Comment: @Fravadona yes I am using ubuntu.

Comment: @Ivan This does not help me, it's all fine until I run the bash script.
it give me an error: sed: -e expression #1, char 12: unknown option to `s'

Comment: A guess here, maybe you have something in your environment (ex. PATH) that points to a different implementation of sed than the one the script uses?  Add absolute path to sed to verify that.

Comment: Your script file seems to have CRLF line endings, you should strip them with `sed -i $'s/\r$//' myscript.sh`